# Silverlight 2104 Error w/ MVC project as Host

Tags: asp.net-mvc, silverlight-4.0

I have a really odd 2104 error occurring when I am hosting a Silverlight control in my MVC site.

If I go to http://mywebsite.com/SomeController then the Silverlight application will load correctly. 
However, if I go to http://mywebsite.com/SomeController/Index then it fails to load and I get the 2104 error. I tried to change the Action name to something other than index, but still no luck.

Right now, it's just boilerplate Silverlight control code, but I need to add some initParams to it, so I need my action to look like http://mywebsite.com/SomeController/Index/1/2

Does anyone have any ideas on what could be causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code 2104 is "Could not download the Silverlight application. Check web server settings".
[List of codes are here.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/silverlight_sdk/archive/2009/07/08/silverlight-plug-in-error-messages.aspx)

You are likely using a relative URL for your silverlight object, which doesn't resolve correctly if you are in a subdirectory.

Use the tilde syntax to correctly point to your silverlight object:

```
<param name="source" value="<% = Url.Content("~/ClientBin/MySilverlightThing.xap") %>"/>
```

Comment: Yeah you're right - I was actually just typing this in as the answer. I'm still not sure why it worked if I went to the base path without the action name, but not if I included the action name.

Comment: I'm not an expert how MVC works behind-the-scenes, but the server might have seen "/SomeController" as a file in the root directory instead of a subdirectory.