# Silverlight in MVC application

Tags: silverlight, model-view-controller, iis

We have an mvc application. We have it on our internal servers and when you hit the appliation you are given a log error of 2104 Silverlight app. When we run it locally through VS2010 dev servers it works. in fiddler we get a 404 for the silverlight.js file and the xap file. Our mime types look correct and our paths look correct. We have this silverlight code in our Views / Prototypes / Home file. we have ../../ClientBin as our path and the silverlight.js file is just as it is src=silverlight.js i have tried src=../../silverlight.js. I am guessing it has to do with the paths or the mimi types but they both look correct.

Comment: Without any code it's hard so answer your question but if you are getting 404s then even if your paths may look correct, they are not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We followed this thread and it worked perfectly.

[Silverlight 2104 Error w/ MVC project as Host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4336419/silverlight-2104-error-w-mvc-project-as-host)